# Why the jQuery events are not fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I thinkg I doing something wrong, but the events only works if the selector is `document`. Otherwise, not happens.

**HTML**

```
<html>                                                                  
   <head>
       <!-- the libraries references here -->
   </head>                                                                 
   <body>
       <div id="canvas"></div>      
   </body>                                                                 
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
/* Click on canvas */
canvasClickEvent = function(e){     
    if(e.shiftKey){
        selectedElement = $(this).attr("id");
    }
}

/* Events */
$(document).ready(documentLoadEvent);
$(document).click(canvasClickEvent); //this works, but is wrong
//$("#canvas").click(canvasClickEvent); --this is what I want, but not works
$(document).dblclick(canvasDblClickEvent);
```

If I replace the document by the div name like `$('#canvas').click(canvasClickEvent);`, the click event is not called. It's only works if the selector is `document`, but the element passed to the function always has the attibs like `undefined`.

What might be happening?

Comment: Hmm - working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/nzTDY/

Comment: Does anything go inside `#canvas` or is it empty?

Comment: @muistooshort SVG will be drawn in it, but without this don't works. With text and without text, with CSS and without CSS, don't works.

Comment: Is your ID unique on the page? If there are two IDs that are the same only the first one will have the event

Comment: Also working fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/4CXFn/

Comment: Here worked on JsFiddle in Firefox, but not in Opera. In normal execution(not JsFiddle) not worked in no one browser.

Comment: When I put the `$(#canvas).click()` inside `$document.ready()`, it works. Otherwise, don't works. What is the difference?

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição .ready() waits until the dom is ready. If the dom doesn't know about the canvas then you can't bind an event to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that event is attempting to bind the event before the DOM element exists.

If you wrap the events inside of the ready() method you guarantee that the domain exists before your event attempts to bind.

```
$(document).ready( function ()  {
     $("#canvas").click(canvasClickEvent);
}
```

The ready() method is dependent on the browsers DOMContentLoaded event which basically means the DOM is completely loaded in the browser, but does not necessarily mean all the media on the page has completely loaded. Once all media is loaded the onLoad browser event fires.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you put your JavaScript code BEFORE the html code. So, when the JavaScript code runs, the elements to be dealt with is not loaded into the DOM yet. (That's why you got "undefined")

Just put your script AFTER the related HTML code. Or put it inside the pageLoad event:

```
$(function(){
    ....
})
```